# R: loop and operation on file name in a directory

Tags: r, loops, filenames

I have a directory in which I have several files for several sites and years, with exactly the same internal structure. I want to merge (rbind) each files that are from the same sites.
Here is the code that is working for one site (define in "pattern"), but instead of doing this manualy for each site name, I want to create a loop that is doing this for all the site.

```
ls1 <- list.files(path = dossier, pattern = "CH", all.files = FALSE,
              full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
              ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
ld1 <- lapply(ls1, function(x) read.csv(file=file.path(dossier,x), sep=",", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
tot1 <- do.call("rbind", ld1)
write.table(tot1, file=file.path(dossier,"CH-Oe1_2002-2006.csv"),col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, sep=";")

ls2 <- list.files(path = dossier, pattern = "FR-Fon", all.files = FALSE,
              full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
              ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
ld2 <- lapply(ls2, function(x) read.csv(file=file.path(dossier,x), sep=",", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
tot2 <- do.call("rbind", ld2)
write.table(tot2, file=file.path(dossier,"FR-Fon_2002-2006.csv"),col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, sep=";")

ls3 <- list.files(path = dossier, pattern = "FR-Gri", all.files = FALSE,
              full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
              ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
ld3 <- lapply(ls3, function(x) read.csv(file=file.path(dossier,x), sep=",", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
tot3 <- do.call("rbind", ld3)
write.table(tot3, file=file.path(dossier,"FR-Gri_2002-2006.csv"),col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, sep=";")

ls4 <- list.files(path = dossier, pattern = "FR-Lq2", all.files = FALSE,
              full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
              ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
ld4 <- lapply(ls4, function(x) read.csv(file=file.path(dossier,x), sep=",", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
tot4 <- do.call("rbind", ld4)
write.table(tot4, file=file.path(dossier,"FR-Lq2_2002-2006.csv"),col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, sep=";")
```

So, what is changing here is : the name in "pattern" and the name to save in write.table.

Any idea to simplify this? 
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Just put your pattern names in a vector and loop over them using `lapply`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for(runPat in c("CH","FR-Fon","FR-Gri","FR-Lq2"))  
  ls <- list.files(path = dossier, pattern = runPat, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
  ld <- lapply(ls, function(x) read.csv(file=file.path(dossier,x), sep=",", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
  tot <- do.call("rbind", ld)
  write.table(tot2, file=file.path(dossier,sprintf("%s_2002-2006.csv",runPat)),col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, sep=";")
}
```

Update: (to 2end comment) you mean something like this?

```
allCont  <- c("CH", "FR")
allSites <- c("", "Fon", "Gri", "Lq2")

for(runCont in allCont){
  for(runSize in allSites){
    if(length(runSite)>0){
      runPat <- sprintf("%s-%s",runCont,runSite)
    }else{
      runPat <- runCont
    }
    ls <- list.files(path = dossier, pattern = runPat, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
    ld <- lapply(ls, function(x) read.csv(file=file.path(dossier,x), sep=",", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
    tot <- do.call("rbind", ld)
    write.table(tot2, file=file.path(dossier,sprintf("%s_2002-2006.csv",runPat)),col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, sep=";")
  }

}
```

how about replacing the two Loops above by

```
allCNT <- dir()
for (runCnt in allCNT){
  allSites <- dir(runCnt)
  for (runSite in allSites){

  }
}
```

?

Comment: I removed my answer as it was nearly identical. One note, doing this in a for loop is perfectly fine in this case as no objects are built up with each iteration.

Comment: This is really nice answer in the case I have like this 4 sites. It works, but I want to do this for hundred of site names in the same directory, so it would take time to put the name into runPat iteration. The standard name of one file is : CC-Sss.yyyy.synth.hourly.allvars.csv. CC stand for country (as in the example CH, FR...in capital letters) and sss stand for site (as in the example: Fon, Lq2), sss can be capital or not and numbers. yyyy stands for years. Can we improve this based on the previous answer?

Comment: you can use the `dir` function to get all the files and subfolders in a directory and afterwards use e.g. `regexp` function to get the patterns you are looking for

Comment: @ HolgerBarlt: In answer to your update, this looks good too, but I want to avoid creating a vector with all the names c("CH", "FR"...) because actually, I have hundred of them..so it would be too long. You are right, I should use something with dir and regexp...I'm trying, but not very familiar !

Comment: See latest answer update? If you do not provide more Details on the structure of your filesystem a more detailed answer is difficult...

Comment: Sorry. To summarize: I have a folder with files that have exactly the same structure. Each file have the name : CC-Sss.yyyy.synth.hourly.allvars.csv , for example: FR-Lq2.2002.synth.hourly.allvars.csv FR-Lq2.2003.synth.hourly.allvars.csv CH-Oe1.2005.synth.hourly.allvars.csv CH-Oe1.2006.synth.hourly.allvars.csv etc....and I want to merge file of the same site (all CH-Oe1 together for exemple). But I have hundred of CC-Sss.yyyy.synth.hourly.allvars.csv in the folder. So it would be too long to manually write "CH...FR....". I should use a general way to read CC-Sss and merge them.

Comment: Finally the simplest way to explain is that I want to merge (rbind) the files that have the same starting name "CC-Sss" in the folder...